# Get only protected members via .net reflection

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

This returns all non-public instance properties:

```
var instanceNonPublic = currentType.GetProperties (BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                   BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

But is there any way to determine which access modifier applies to each property? `private`, `internal` or `protected`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since properties are made of `get` method and `set` method you can iterate them and filter the relevant `PropertyInfo`s using their `get` and `set` methods' access modifiers:

```
var instancePrivate = currentType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(x => x.GetMethod.IsPrivate &&
                x.SetMethod.IsPrivate);
```

Those are the interesting access modifiers:

- `IsPrivate` indicates that the method is `private`.
- `IsFamily` indicates that the method is `protected`.
- `IsAssembly` indicates that the method is `internal`.

Other way to elegantly set the filter is using `FindMembers`:

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    ...
    var instancePrivate = currentType.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Property,
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                  BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                                  PrivateMemberFilter, null);
        .OfType<PropertyInfo>();
    ...
}

static readonly MemberFilter PrivatePropertyFilter = (objMemberInfo, objSearch) =>
{
    PropertyInfo info = (objMemberInfo as PropertyInfo);
    if (info == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return info.GetMethod.IsPrivate && info.SetMethod.IsPrivate;
};
```